# Using SASS on my Debian server

Tags: terminal, debian, process

Ok here's a quick question. I have a debian server with sass (driven by ruby) installed. To compile a sass file to a css file, yo do:

```
sass --watch style.scss:style.css
```

If I run this on my server through a terminal. Is that process still running when I close the terminal? If not, how do I keep it running? And how do I stop it if I want to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a process to be running even when you disconnect from a server, use [`nohup`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup).

```
nohup sass --watch style.scss:style.css &
```

The `&` will start the job in the background. `nohup` makes sure that even when you log out, the process continues. Every output will be logged to `nohup.out`.

You can also have several output files for stdout and stderr:

```
nohup --watch style.scss:style.css > main.log 2> err.log &
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you! How can I stop the process?

Comment: I guess you would have to run `ps aux | grep nohup | grep -v grep` and then run `kill PID` where PID is the number in the second column. Haven't found a better way to do that yet.

Comment: I've been using `pkill sass` to stop my processes (under Ubuntu 12.04). That worries me a little since it's not a delicate approach, but I'm the only person using my server and so far it hasn't killed anything unintended.